# iOS app framework crashed

Tags: swift, xcode7.3

While I am trying to deploy an app on my **phone**, The app **crashed** and here is the console **log**:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCloudKit.dylib   Referenced
>   from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3327C878-41D2-4394-9D3E-F5FA1C126941/ProximityContent.app/ProximityContent
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3327C878-41D2-4394-9D3E-F5FA1C126941/ProximityContent.app/Frameworks/libswiftCloudKit.dylib:
>   code signing blocked mmap() of
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3327C878-41D2-4394-9D3E-F5FA1C126941/ProximityContent.app/Frameworks/libswiftCloudKit.dylib'

This happens for all other applications in my **xcode**.

Comment: update your xcode and clean your projects

Comment: I tried so, but no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue (were having EXC_BAD_ACCESS for AVFoundation) by cleaning (cmd+k) and then cleaning the folder (cmd + shift + K).

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Framework **deployment info** means framework supported OS.

Your project supported OS version and framework supported OS version check required.